# Associating a userID to user uploaded data in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts

I asked this question a couple of days ago, but deleted it and I am adding more clarification here in what I'm looking at.

So what I have is a process where a user uploads a CSV and the CSV is then parsed by PapaParse and then sent server side and ultimately inserted into MongoDb.

My problem is that none of these uploads are linked to the specific user, so anyone will have access to every upload the way things look now.

What I tried to do is loop through the upload data, which looks like this;

```
var document = [{object}, {object}, {object}, {object}, {object}... ];
```

I used a for loop to loop through each of the objects and add an `_id` field this contains the user's id via `var currentUser = this.userId;`

```
Meteor.methods({
  insert: function(document){
    var currentUser = this.userId;
    var newDocument = document;

    for(var i = 0; i < newDocument.length; i++){
      newDocument[i]._id = currentUser;
    }

     Bank.insert(newDocument);
  }
```

Problem is that memory allocation is an issue for larger uploads and meteor simply crashes trying to loop through all the objects and individually adding the _id key to each object in each cell of the array.

When the document is inserted into MongoDB, it looks like this:

[image]

I know in my previous post, someone mentioned that MongoDB's insert method doesn't take an array as input, but somehow in my case, it does because the above screenshot is exactly how the document looks before being inserted into MongoDB. So basically, each object is a new document inside a MongoDB. I'm trying to find a way to bind the user's userID with each document in the databse.

Is there another way to associate the upload with the unique current user other than looping through the entire data set, which could be in the tens of thousands on some users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just do?

```
Meteor.methods({
  insert: function(document){
    var currentUser = Meteor.userId();
    var newDocument = document;    
    Bank.insert({userId: currentUser, data: newDocument});
  }
});
```

Now each document in your collection will have two *keys*: `userId` and `data`. The latter will be your array.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. Now the user's Id is associated with the collection like this: https://i.gyazo.com/171e03faa16380bc3d2ce8709276f790.png So, if I'm understanding this correctly, each document in the database will be an object with a userId key and a data key?

Comment: Another question I have: If the same user uploads more CSV files, will they be located in the same object document without creating additional documents under the same userID? Likewise, is it possible for the user to add more data/upload additional CSV files in under the same object?

Comment: To your first question, yes, each document in `Bank` will contain `{_id: String, userId: String, data: Array of objects}`. To your second question: it would be possible to add more csv files to the original document but I wouldn't recommend that. Remember that Mongo documents are limited to 16MB each.